# Basic integer division in PHP is failing - Am clueless

Tags: php, integer

(Looks like something's wrong with my environment / system. Am analyzing it currently. Every logical answer was tried and it failed. So, will report back once I have more to share. Thanks for the answers!)

I have written some simple PHP code to calculate the duration between two dates, and do some basic arithmetic, to calculate some percentage value.

I am at a loss of clues on why this is not working! Seems to me that a variable is treated as an integer on one line and a string on another.

```
$start_DT = new DateTime($startdate); // e.g. 2011-06-07
$end_DT   = new DateTime($enddate);   // e.g. 2011-06-14
$today_DT = new DateTime("now");      // 2011-06-09

$duration       = date_diff($end_DT, $start_DT)->d;
$days_remaining = date_diff($end_DT, $today_DT)->d;

echo $days_remaining; // This outputs a value of "4" in my specific case
echo $duration;       // This outputs a value of "7" for my specific case. 

$percentage_dur_complete = $days_remaining / $duration;

echo $percentage_dur_complete; // This gives a value of NAN

// This line says that I am dividing my zero, to imply that 
// $duration might be a string. 
$percentage_dur_complete = $days_remaining / (float) $duration;
```

Am I missing something basic? I am a relative newbie (2 months) to PHP. I really hope (with the risk of appearing stupid) that there's something I've missed out.

Thanks!

Comment: date_diff returns a DateInterval, not an integer.

Comment: One way to check what type each variable is before the division is to use `var_dump( $myvar )`, which will tell you the type and value of `$myvar`. More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: Yes, I figured that out. I am accessing its member variable for days (->d) to get the actual integer within it.

Comment: If I do `var_dump`, then both numbers are integers and `$percentage_dur_complete` contains a proper number. There must be something else wrong. Are you sure `$startdate` and `$enddate` are correctly set?

Comment: @Paul Sonier - Maybe the OP knows that?  

Maybe that's why the OP selects the $d member of the object?  

Maybe you should look at all of the little squigglies before putting people down?  

And maybe everybody else should too before upvoting a snide and wrong remark?

Comment: For sanity check, what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: What's wierd(er) is that every OTHER operation with $duration fails, and every OTHER works.

Comment: var_dump gives me int(7) for $duration

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$percentage_dur_complete = (int)$days_remaining / (int)$duration;
```

EDIT:
This works for me...

```
<?php 
$startdate = '2011-06-05';
$enddate = '2011-06-12';
$today_DT = new DateTime("now");
$start_DT = new DateTime($startdate); // e.g. 2011-06-07
$end_DT   = new DateTime($enddate);  
$duration       = date_diff($end_DT, $start_DT)->d;
$days_remaining = date_diff($end_DT, $today_DT)->d;
var_dump ($duration);
var_dump ($days_remaining);
$percentage_dur_complete = $days_remaining / $duration *100;
echo ($percentage_dur_complete);
?>
```

If it doesnt for you, it is most definitely an issue with your PHP installation/version!

Comment: Sleep doesn't work, although I wonder why it makes sense to add? Seems a bit unrelated?

Comment: Yes, its likely something with my system that's wonky. Thanks for the response. Will have to figure out what's going on at my end

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and modified it a bit (formatted output, but more importantly passed direct strings into the `DateTime` functions):

```
$start_DT = new DateTime('2011-06-07');

$end_DT = new DateTime('2011-06-14');

$today_DT = new DateTime("now"); 

$duration = date_diff($end_DT, $start_DT)->d;

$days_remaining = date_diff($end_DT, $today_DT)->d;

echo $days_remaining . "<br>"; 

echo $duration . "<br>";

$percentage_dur_complete = $days_remaining / $duration;

echo $percentage_dur_complete . "<br>";

$percentage_dur_complete = $days_remaining / (float) $duration;

echo $percentage_dur_complete . "<br>";
```

And I'm getting output that looks like this:

```
5
7
0.71428571428571
0.71428571428571
```

My hunch is that you're not passing what you think you're passing to generate `$start_DT` and `$end_DT`.

Comment: I tried this out. What's wierd(er) is that every OTHER operation with $duration fails, and every OTHER works. 

So, if I add an extra echo for $duration, my own code works OK. Can't figure out why

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You mean that it alternates between working and not working?

Comment: So, if I copy paste your code as-is, this is what I get:

3

7

NAN

0.42857142857143

Comment: Yes, every alternate operation with $duration works. I know it sounds silly. :(

Comment: What locale are you in? Maybe the `DateTime` constructor is not parsing the date correctly because it's looking for another format.

Comment: Well, I am in English_US on a Windows sytem. BTW, on a different note var_dump for $duration gives me int(7).

Comment: Try using [`format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to dump the values of those three `DateTime`s at the top - maybe we'll see one or more of them as something not what we expect.

Comment: I formatted each of them with ->format('Y M d') and got this:
2011 Jun 07
2011 Jun 14
2011 Jun 10

Interestingly, if I format it using ->format('Y M D') I instead get: 2011 Jun Tue, 2011 Jun Tue..

Comment: `D` vs `d` is expected behavior, those are just formatting parameters (and both are Tue since both dates fall on a Tuesday). I'm stumped though. Maybe try getting the days using [`DateInterval::format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php) instead.

Comment: Had tried that as well. The output was as expected. For now, I'll add dummy operations on every other line (which does make it work), but I can't live with that forever. Will see if there's something else that's wonky with my system (all other code seems to work perfectly OK)..

Comment: OK, something weirder. I added a dummy operation, and the division works OK. BUT, once I do something like:  var_dump($percentage_complete *100); it gives this as the output: float(;.OLNHKIOLNHKIP)

Comment: Sounds like there is something very screwy going on with your installation. Can you copy your code to another machine running PHP and test there?

Comment: Looks like it. Will give it a try and report back (Might take a bit of time).. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet that DateTime's constructor is having trouble with your incoming dates. Try this:

```
$startdate = "2011-06-07";
$enddate = "2011-06-14";

$start_DT = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-j',$startdate);
$end_DT = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-j',$enddate);
$today_DT = new DateTime("now");

$duration = date_diff($end_DT, $start_DT)->d;
$days_remaining = date_diff($end_DT, $today_DT)->d;

echo $days_remaining . "<br>\n";
echo $duration . "<br>\n";

$percentage_dur_complete = $days_remaining / $duration;
echo $percentage_dur_complete . "<br>\n";

$percentage_dur_complete = $days_remaining / (float) $duration;
echo $percentage_dur_complete . "<br>\n";
```

Make sure the format string matches how you're passing in your date strings (i.e. 'j' for days with leading zero, 'd' for days without).

Comment: Thanks. This worked for a bit, and then stopped working. I think something is wrong in my install. Will reinstall everything / try it on a different system. Even if I take your code as is, it works intermittently. Makes me believe that its my system

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using PHP 5.3.1 and I upgraded to 5.4.17 to solve the issue. Don't waste time trying to find a workaround like I did initially.

Comment: is your answer really related to date_diff issue that is exposed in the question?